# SQL - Unable to insert a DATE apart from the default sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to insert a DATE value into my table however I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

this is my statement:

```
INSERT INTO TstResults (tstcode, EmpID, fname, sname, tstDate, tstRslt)
VALUES ((Select tstcode from Tests where Freq ='6mnths')
       ,(Select EmpID from Employees where fname = 'Sam')
       ,'Sam'
       ,'Fisher'
       ,01-JUN-15
       ,'A');
```

Whenever I type in a date it gives me that above error. In the TstResults the tstDate column has a default value of sysdate. The only way I can out the data in the table is by removing the tstDate from the insert statement.

Comment: The correct syntax for a date literal is documented in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single inverted commas around the date.

```
INSERT INTO TstResults (tstcode, EmpID, fname, sname, tstDate, tstRslt)
VALUES
( (Select tstcode from Tests where Freq ='6mnths'), (Select EmpID from Employees where fname = 'Sam'), 'Sam', 'Fisher', '01-JUN-15', 'A');
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained by *a_horse_with_no_name* in a comment above, for hard-coded date, you might want to use a [*date literal*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) : `DATE '2015-06-15'`

On the other hand, Oracle can convert from *strings* to date too. Either *implicitly* using the client `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter as demonstrated in the other answers. Or *explicitly* by calling the `TO_DATE`  function with the correct parameters.  In your particular case: `TO_DATE('01-JUN-15', 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')`

Using *implicit* conversion might seems *quick-and-easy* but, please note however that *implicit* conversion might work today but fail in the future some clients connecting to the DB with different settings (say for client having a different *locale*).

---

So, as of myself, I would push toward using a date literal:

```
INSERT INTO TstResults (tstcode, EmpID, fname, sname, tstDate, tstRslt)
VALUES ((Select tstcode from Tests where Freq ='6mnths')
       ,(Select EmpID from Employees where fname = 'Sam')
       ,'Sam'
       ,'Fisher'
       , DATE '2015-06-15'
       ,'A')
```

Or, if you really don't want / can't use the date literal:

```
INSERT INTO TstResults (tstcode, EmpID, fname, sname, tstDate, tstRslt)
VALUES ((Select tstcode from Tests where Freq ='6mnths')
       ,(Select EmpID from Employees where fname = 'Sam')
       ,'Sam'
       ,'Fisher'
       ,TO_DATE('01-JUN-15', 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
       ,'A')
```

Comment: Using month *names* is still not a good idea even when using a format mask. `TO_DATE('01-JUN-15', 'DD-MON-YY')` will fail for a client using e.g. a French or Italian locale.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name While typing, I forgot the _third_ parameter of `TO_DATE`. If I'm not _too_ wrong, using `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'` will ensure the conversion will work, whatever is the client locale. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: That is an alternative yes (I didn't see that when writing my comment for some reason). But personally I would prefer the ISO date literals as they are shorter to type and always unumbigous.

Comment: A plus for using code that forces the format into it, and making it more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around the date:

```
INSERT INTO TstResults (tstcode, EmpID, fname, sname, tstDate, tstRslt)
VALUES ((Select tstcode from Tests where Freq ='6mnths')
       ,(Select EmpID from Employees where fname = 'Sam')
       ,'Sam'
       ,'Fisher'
       ,'01-JUN-15'
       ,'A');
```

Comment: This is subject to implicit data type conversion and not recommended (it might fail depending on NLS settings of the SQL client used) Use a proper date literal instead, e.g. `DATE '2015-06-15'` or the `to_date()` function with a format mask.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I took the liberty to summarize as an answer your two interesting comments on this page. Please let me know if this wasn't appropriate -- in that case I will remove that answer.